# In elementary number theory, something

Tags: elementary-number-theory

when I saw the whose answer sheet 
It is written that $$(p-1)!\equiv1(p-2)3(p-4)5...(p-2)(p-(p-1))\equiv1^23^25^2...(p-2)^2 \pmod{p}$$

I don't understand why the middle term turns into the square term.

Answer (score 1):

The congruence you wrote holds if $(p-1)/2$ is an even number.
In general for an odd number $p$, 
$$(p-1)!=\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}(2k-1)\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}(2k)
\equiv (-1)^{(p-1)/2}\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}(2k-1)\cdot \prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}(p-2k)\\
\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2}(2k-1)^2
=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\cdot 1^23^25^2\cdots(p-2)^2 \pmod{p}.$$

Comment: Which is also congruent , modulo $ p, $  to $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}((p-1)/2)!^2$